Flutter: Optimizing cacheWidth/cacheHeight for responsive images on desktop/web without flickering
I'm working on optimizing image performance in a Flutter app where high-resolution images are used. On smaller devices, these images tend to consume more memory than needed, so I implemented cacheWidth and cacheHeight to resize the images and reduce memory usage. This approach worked well for mobile devices, and the memory consumption dropped significantly.
However, when I applied this to desktop and web, I encountered an issue with responsiveness. On larger screens, the images didn't scale properly, so I tried making them responsive using LayoutBuilder to dynamically adjust cacheWidth and cacheHeight based on the window size.
The problem is, on desktop/web, the window size is unpredictable because users control the window or monitor sizes. When I resize the window, the image refreshes or flickers, and it negatively impacts the user experience.
What I Tried and Expected:

Using cacheWidth and cacheHeight:

I implemented these parameters to optimize image loading, which worked perfectly on mobile devices (where the window size is fixed).
On mobile, the images resized correctly, reducing memory usage without compromising quality.


LayoutBuilder for responsive images:

I used LayoutBuilder to calculate cacheWidth and cacheHeight dynamically based on the window size, expecting the images to smoothly resize on desktop/web without flickering.
I thought this would help manage the unpredictability of window sizes on desktop.


Using ResizeImage:

I also tried ResizeImage to control the size of the image, hoping it would solve the issue. However, the flickering still occurred when resizing the window on desktop/web.



What actually happened:
On desktop/web, every time the window is resized, the image refreshes and flickers, which creates a poor user experience. This flickering occurs because the image seems to be reloaded each time the window changes, unlike on mobile where the size is static.
Code Example:  Code Live
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum ImageSourceType { network, asset }

class ResponsiveImage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ResponsiveImage({
    required this.imagePath,
    required this.source,
    super.key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.fit,
  });

  final BoxFit? fit;
  final double? height;
  final String imagePath;
  final ImageSourceType source;
  final double? width;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        final double pixelRatio = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
        final double usedWidth = width ?? constraints.maxWidth;
        final double usedHeight = height ?? constraints.maxHeight;
        final int cacheWidth = (usedWidth * pixelRatio).round();
        final int cacheHeight = (usedHeight * pixelRatio).round();

        // Use ResizeImage to resize the image if needed
        ImageProvider imageProvider;

        if (source == ImageSourceType.network) {
          // Use ResizeImage with NetworkImage to resize it if necessary
          imageProvider = ResizeImage(
            NetworkImage(imagePath),
            width: cacheWidth,
            height: cacheHeight,
          );
        } else {
          // Use ResizeImage with AssetImage to resize it if necessary
          imageProvider = ResizeImage(
            AssetImage(imagePath),
            width: cacheWidth,
            height: cacheHeight,
          );
        }

        // Now the Image widget will use ResizeImage to handle cacheWidth and cacheHeight
        return Image(
          image: imageProvider,
          width: usedWidth,
          height: usedHeight,
          fit: fit ?? BoxFit.cover,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

Has anyone faced this issue before when working with cacheWidth and cacheHeight for responsive images, especially on desktop and web? I'm looking for a solution that ensures images are responsive without causing flickering or refreshing each time the window is resized. I also tried using ResizeImage, but the issue persists.
Any insights or best practices for handling responsive images efficiently in Flutter would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Looks like the cacheWidth and cacheHeight are ignored on the web platform as per the last statement in the documentation here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html
